# C# audio library with smooth looping?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I'm looking for an audio library that works with .NET that allows for smooth looping. I've tried DirectX AudioVideoPlayback and Mentalis. Both are easy to use, but the looping skips a bit. I'm wondering if that's my fault or theirs. I have sound samples that I know can loop cleanly (WinAmp can do it fine) but I can't get my C# app to do the same. What library could I use, or what could I fix in my app to get it to loop cleanly with the libraries I have?

UPDATE: FMOD has been able to loop my audio, but the problem is that the .net wrapper I have only loads files one way. I can't play a sound effect more than once because they get disposed when playback finishes, and sometimes it hangs whenever a sound is supposed to be played. I know I could just reload the sound to play it again, but I don't want to hit the disk every time a gunshot is fired. Should I just reach into the C++ layer myself and skip the .NET wrappers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try FMOD which is free for non-commercial use.

I would double-check that the sound really loops cleanly - specifically, that the first sample and the last sample are close (or equal), otherwise you'll hear a click. WinAMP could conceivably do some special processing to eliminate the click.

UPDATE: FMOD comes with a whole bunch of samples in C# that show the right way to do stuff. The example called "3d" shows, among other things, a cleanly looping sound. You should be able to rip out the code that handles the looping without utilising the 3D features.

Comment: It's game music - I edited the sample myself to trim it as finely as I could. In my game, it's not really a click, it's that it pauses for a fraction of a second and then restarts. In fact it doesn't restart at the beginning, but at the time after the pause. So it's almost as if it's just silent for a bit.